# Is it correct to use "the education of a nation's youth"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

In the following sentence, is it correct to use the phrase 'the education of a nation's youth'?  is the word 'youth' singular or plural?

> The education of a nation's youth will shape its future.

Answer (score 2):

That is a perfectly valid phrase. In this case, ***youth*** is a *mass noun*, uncountable, to refer to young population of a nation as a whole.

Thus, it is saying that how the young people of a nation are education, or how well they are educated, will shape the future of that nation.

(Technically, *its* is ambiguous, and could refer to the nation or the "nation's youth", but it's fairly clear that it means the nation - and the future of a nation's youth is arguable the nation's future in any case.)